# Why does Closure Compiler favor !0 in lieu of true?

Tags: javascript, operators, google-closure-compiler, primitive

Example:

```
var formatDate = function(d) {
  return dateFormat(d, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss", true);
}
```

Is compiled to:

```
var formatDate = function(a) {
  return dateFormat(a, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss", !0);
};
```

!0 feels like a logical operation in place a Javascript primitive, which intuitively seems like it should be more expensive. Is this not the case? Why not?

Comment: Because it is two characters shorter.

Comment: The runtime in this case can treat that `!0` as being exactly equivalent to `true`; in other words, it's pretty likely that it literally makes no difference once the code actually runs, and before that it saves 2 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gzip compression was found to be better. Closure-compiler uses heuristics to try to produce a file that will gzip to the smallest possible size.

Note: In some cases this makes the non-gzipped file bigger. In this specific case it's a win for the raw file and the gzip version.